# Use exchange server as personal email server

Tags: email, exchange

Does anyone use Microsoft Exchange Server as your personal/small biz email server (< 20 users)? Is it hard to configure? Is it resource intensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to do this using a virtual machine on a HP ProLiant pedestal server, running Exchange 2007.  While it was a good learning experience, I do not any more for the following reasons:

- It used a lot of RAM, which could be better used for other VMs
- Running the server 24/7/365 used far too much electricity
- In the event of downtime, losing emails can cause serious stress
- It's an unnecessary admin headache which I would rather somebody else do

Even with SBS customers, I no longer set up Exchange for small firms.  I use Exchange Online instead, which also comes part of [BPOS](http://www.microsoft.com/online/business-productivity.aspx).  BPOS will be replaced with [Office 365](http://office365.microsoft.com/en-US/online-services.aspx) some time early next year, where the upgrade will be seemless for existing users.

Comment: You can email me at the address on my profile if you want a free trial of Exchange Online.

Answer (score 0):

I never used it for that small of a deployment(it was always SBS for that size).  With a scale that low it isn't resource intensive.  With the UNC network 1 linux mail server was able to replace 3 exchange servers in a clustered servers campus environment.  So yes, linux mail servers scale better(sendmail/postfix/etc).

Comment: note SBS has a tweaked version of exchange with limits on mail store sizes etc, so this could be construed as using exchange in some form

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't be more cost effective to use google apps or office365 or a hosted exchange solution? you will not worry to maintain and administer the servers.

some links:
http://www.microsoft.com/online/exchange-hosted-services.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/online/business-productivity.aspx
http://www.office365.com
http://google.com/a